# What is the cleanest way to animate without .animate() jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, svg

I had a nice idea, namely to use the 'stroke-dasharray' CSS-attribute that can be used on SVG objects, to stroke the paths on the page, giving it a nice artistic way for shapes to appear.

It works perfectly and is supported by most modern browsers as well as phones.

A nice jsfiddle of what I've made can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/G6ECE/

The code that makes the whole thing tick right now:

```
   num=0;
   setInterval(function(){
       updateStroke(num);
       num+= 0.2;
   }, 1);
   function updateStroke(num){

       // stroke-dasharray is a list of two or more numbers. In this example, percentage values are used to make all paths fully stroked at the end of the animation, irregardless of path length.
       $('svg path').css({stroke:'#00FF00','stroke-dasharray':num+'% '+(100-num)+'%'});
   }
```

Obviously this is a very basic, ugly way to animate something.

I want to customize the animation a little: I want to be able to add a custom animation length and also use different easings.  Unfortunately, the jQuery $()**.animate()** function that I'd normally use to animate CSS attributes, does not support non-numeric values.

As [stroke-dasharray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) uses two or more numeric(pixel or percentage) values to work, I need an alternative for .animate()

What would be the cleanest way to do this? (with using as much existing jQuery functionality as possible, and as little as possible re-inventing an animation framework)

Comment: Instead of `setInterval` you should use `requestAnimationFrame`, see e.g http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/.

Answer (score 1):

What about CSS transitions? They also have a better performance than jQuery animations.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

But be sure not to use both for the same property as jQuery animations interfere with CSS transitions.

Comment: CSS transitions (or even CSS animations) might very well work, in this simple example. It is a great idea, and that's why you get an upvote :).  But I am looking for a way that gives me more control: CSS animations quickly become tiresome/confusing when you want to animate one element in different ways depending on the circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I have been working with a nice robust cross-browser javascript animation object. Once you understand the way it is used, it becomes quite seamless for all or your SVG animations.  It can be attached to any svg element and control associated values.

There are some examples that show the various choices of animation performance(linear, quadratic, ease,etc) at:
[http://www.svgDiscovery.com/](http://www.svgDiscovery.com)

Below is the object:

```
var AnimateJS=function(options){
    this.options=options
    var start = new Date
    var iT = setInterval(
    function(){
        var timePassed = new Date - start
        var progress = timePassed / options.duration
        if (progress > 1) progress = 1
        this.progress=progress
        var delta = options.delta(progress)
        options.output(delta)
        if (progress == 1)clearInterval(iT);
    },options.delay)
}
```